# Check if value in database table Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that would count the number of times a value is in a database. However in the code behind for loop when it reaches 
`(int)command.ExecuteScalar();` the loop stops and asks to supply parameter for @invoice2.

Stored Procedure:

```
select count(*) as CountInvoice where invoice1=@invoice1 or @invoice2=@invoice`2
```

Code Behind:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_Count", conn))
{

    foreach (TextBox textBox in placehldr1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {

        count += 1;

        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        string invoice = textBox.Text.TrimEnd();
        string parameter = string.Format("@invoice{0}", count);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter, invoice);
        int invoiceCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

        if (invoiceCount > 0)
        {

            lblError.Text = "Invoice number already exist";
            return;
        }
        command.Parameters.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: Please Put your Store procedure and the whole code here

Comment: Please provide more details

Comment: You're executing the script providing only one parameter at a time, your script defines 2 parameters it requires.

Comment: so how would provide the 2nd parameter

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ; what would have to do to eliminate it running one parameter at a time

Comment: You are using count += 1; in loop and passing it as invoice number. Do you have invoice number separately? If you have 2 param in SP, then pass both of them. command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invoice1",invoiceNumber1); command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invoice2",invoiceNumber2)

Comment: @Chidambaram; from what I gather the count is what increment to get the parameters; and invoice stores the data from each textbox. but the ExecuteScalar just does one parameter

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work better as it factors in the two parameters.

```
select count(*) as CountInvoice where invoice1=@invoice1 or invoice2=@invoice2


using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_Count", conn))
{

    foreach (TextBox textBox in placehldr1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {

        count1 += 1;
        count2 += 1;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        string invoice = textBox.Text.TrimEnd();
        string parameter1 = string.Format("@invoice1", count1);
        string parameter2 = string.Format("@invoice2", count2);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter, invoice);
        int invoiceCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

        if (invoiceCount > 0)
        {

            lblError.Text = "Invoice number already exist";
            return;
        }
        command.Parameters.Clear();
    }
```